# Multiple Event on One Element

Tags: javascript

I try learning js. I wanna add multiple event on one element. I tried but my code did not work. Anyone can correct my code.
My code:

```
var val=document.getElementById("val").addEventListener("event",change1);
function change1(){
  if ("event"="click"){
    document.getElementById("div1").style.color="red";
    var inp=document.getElementsByName("customer");
    inp[0].value="test user";
  }
  else if ("event"="mouseover"){
    document.getElementById("div1").style.color="blue";
    var inp=document.getElementsByName("customer");
    inp[0].value="Wellcome Customer";
  }
}
```

Comment: The first argument for `.addEventListener()` is a string of the name of the type of event you want to listen for. `"event"` isn't a valid event type, however, `"click"` is an example of one, and `"mouseover"` is an example of another. So, if you want to listen for _two_ events, you're going to have to add _two_ event listeners

Answer (score 0):

You should add a callback for each event (it also increase readability and debugging speed):

```
var val=document.getElementById("val").addEventListener("click",change1);
var val=document.getElementById("val").addEventListener("mouseover",change2);

function change1(){
    document.getElementById("div1").style.color="red";
    var inp=document.getElementsByName("customer");
    inp[0].value="test user";
}

function change2(){
    document.getElementById("div1").style.color="blue";
    var inp=document.getElementsByName("customer");
    inp[0].value="Wellcome Customer";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const val = document.getElementById("val");
const div1 = document.getElementById("div1")
const inp = document.getElementsByName('customer')[0];

val.addEventListener("click", eventHandler);
val.addEventListener("mouseover", eventHandler);

function eventHandler(event) {
    if (event.type === "click"){
        div1.style.color = "red";
        inp.value = "test user";
    }
    else if (event.type === "mouseover") {
         div1.style.color = "blue";
         inp.value = "Wellcome Customer";
    }
}
```

1) You don't need assignment here: 
`var val = document.getElementById("val")...`

here `val` contains `undefined` and never used

2) First argument of `addEventListener` must be event type, but not string 'event' ([about events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/type))

3) In if statement `("event"="click")` must be comparison, but not assignment ([about comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators))

4) If you use `div1` and `inp` every time event triggered, find this elements once, assign to variables and then reference to them